# undefined:undefined Twilio Studio Flow SMS Forwarding Function Error

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I've been attempting to create a two-way conversation using SMS forwarding in Twilio Studio flow. I know there are multiple ways to set up SMS forwarding in Twilio, and I have been successful in doing so using functions on their own, TwiML and Studio Flow SMS on the send message widget. However, I am struggling with creating a flow that extends beyond one message. I've added the function for SMS forwarding into my flow, but every time a response is received it displays as "undefined:undefined" as opposed to "+15555555555:Hello SMS", Am i missing something?

Comment: How are you setting this up so far? Can you share the flow you've built (screenshot) and the relevant widgets? I'm not sure Studio is particularly well set up for this use case, but I'm interested in what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the CHAT product from Twilio instead which would manage all of the sessions, conversations and everything else.